# Error/failure with connection device to AWS IOT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I did research on web and stackoverflow, but i didn't find solution.
I have a problem with connect my device MOXA 5105 with AWS. Device publishing data [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9F6t.png)

and I see on AWS monitor that connection, but in test Client I'm not seeing JSONs.
in CloudWatch logs i see this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-06-16 06:09:48.771",
    "logLevel": "ERROR",
    "traceId": "XXXXXX-ebb3-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "status": "Failure",
    "eventType": "Publish-In",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "topicName": "MGate_5105_Test",
    "clientId": "MGate_5105_Test",
    "principalId": "CERTIFICATCODEXXXX",
    "sourceIp": "5.226.117.166",
    "sourcePort": 55194
}
```

My policy which i wrote in AWS IOT is present as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:client/MGate_5105_Test"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:topic/#"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:topic/MGate_5105_Test/#"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:topicfilter/MGate_5105_Test/#"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:thing/MGate_5105_Test"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:GetThingShadow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:thing/MGate_5105_Test"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:DeleteThingShadow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:thing/MGate_5105_Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

where clientID=Thing Name to make it simpler

Answer (score 0):

For the `iot:Publish` and `iot:Receive` actions, the `Resource` section doesn't support MQTT wildcards (`+` and `#`).

```
    ...
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:topic/#"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:topic/MGate_5105_Test/#"
    },
    ...
```

Instead, you can use the `*` wildcard to match multiple topics for these actions.

```
    ...
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:topic/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:topic/MGate_5105_Test/*"
    },
    ...
```

See [Example policies for MQTT clients](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html#pub-sub-policy-cert).